Navigate to a different page after login streamlit
I am building a data analysis and visualization web app using streamlit with firebase authentication. The login is successfully but it has failed to switch to the main dashboard page.
Here is the code.
I have built a custom sidebar and imported it into the main.py page. There is auth logic included the main.py page and on successful login, I want the user to move the dashboard page but I have failed to achieve this functionality!
import streamlit as st
from time import sleep
from streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner import get_script_run_ctx
from streamlit.source_util import get_pages


def get_current_page_name():
    ctx = get_script_run_ctx()
    if ctx is None:
        raise RuntimeError("Couldn't get script context")

    pages = get_pages("")

    return pages[ctx.page_script_hash]["page_name"]


def make_sidebar():
    with st.sidebar:
        st.title("I&M Bank Data Visualizer")
        st.image("images/imbank-logo.png", use_column_width=True)
        st.write("")
        st.write("")

        if st.session_state.get("authentication_status", True):
            st.page_link("pages/1dashboard.py", label="Main Dashboard", icon="")
            st.page_link("pages/otg.py", label="OTG Channels", icon="️")

            st.write("")
            st.write("")

            if st.button("Log out", use_container_width=True):
                logout()

        elif get_current_page_name() != "main":
            # If anyone tries to access a secret page without being logged in,
            # redirect them to the login page
            st.switch_page("main.py")


def logout():
    st.session_state.authentication_status = False
    st.info("Logged out successfully!")
    sleep(0.5)
    st.switch_page("main.py")

import streamlit as st
import pyrebase

from navigation import make_sidebar

# st.session_state['authentication_status'] = False

make_sidebar()

# Access secrets
api_key = st.secrets["general"]["apiKey"]
auth_domain = st.secrets['general']['authDomain']
project_ID = st.secrets['general']['projectId']
database_URL = st.secrets['general']['databaseURL']
storage_Bucket = st.secrets['general']['storageBucket']
messaging_SenderId = st.secrets['general']['messagingSenderId']
appId = st.secrets['general']['appId']
measurementId = st.secrets['general']['measurementId']

# Configuration key
firebaseConfig = {
  "apiKey": api_key,
  "authDomain": auth_domain,
  "projectId": project_ID,
  "databaseURL": database_URL,
  "storageBucket": storage_Bucket,
  "messagingSenderId": messaging_SenderId,
  "appId": appId,
  "measurementId": measurementId
}

# # firebase Authentication
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
auth = firebase.auth()

# # Database
db = firebase.database()
storage = firebase.storage() #not needed for now



# Auth functions
def login(email, password):
    try:
        user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
        st.success("Login Successful!")
        st.session_state['authentication_status'] = True
        st.session_state['user'] = user
        st.balloons()
        print(st.session_state.authentication_status, user)
        st.switch_page("pages/1dashboard.py")
    except:  # noqa: E722
        st.error("Invalid email or password")
        st.session_state['authentication_status'] = False
    
def signup(email, password):
    try:
        user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
        st.success("Signup was successful! Please log in!")
        st.session_state['authentication_status'] = True
        st.session_state['user'] = user
        st.rerun()
    except:  # noqa: E722
        st.error("Email already exists or password is too weak!")
        st.session_state['authentication_status'] = False

# Track Authentiction Status
if 'authentication_status' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['authentication_status'] = None

if 'user' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['user'] = None


# Render forms conditionally
if st.session_state['authentication_status'] is None or st.session_state['authentication_status'] is False:

    st.image("./images/imbank-logo.png", use_column_width=True)

    choice = st.selectbox('Login/Signup',['Login', 'Signup'])

    email = st.text_input("Please enter your email address")
    password = st.text_input("Please enter your password", type="password")


    # Handle Login/Signup

    if choice == 'Login':
        if st.button('Login', use_container_width=True):
            login(email, password)
    elif choice == 'Signup':
        if st.button('Signup', use_container_width=True):
            signup(email, password)

    

# If the user is authenticated

# if st.session_state['authentication_status']:

    
# elif st.session_state['authentication_status'] is False:
#     st.error('Please try logging in again.')

# elif st.session_state['authentication_status'] is None:
#     st.warning('Please log in to continue.')






